# Showing the distance between a point $P$ the line determined by a segment $AB$ is $d=\frac{||AP\times AB||}{||AB||}$

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, cross-product

> Show that in $3$-space the distance $d$ from a point $P$ to the line $L$ through points A and B can be expressed as $$d=\frac{||AP\times AB||}{||AB||} .$$

My diagram of the situation:

[image]

My next thought was to find $\operatorname{proj}_{AB}AP$ and then use,

$d^2 = AP^2 -  (\operatorname{proj}_{AB}AP)^2$

However, this seems to turn into a mess quite quickly and I'm not sure if I'm approaching the question in the best way possible.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of embedding the image. I also adjusted the title, which seemed to misstate the claim; please check that the change really does reflect your intention.

Comment: No, that's what I'm trying to find! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle between the vectors $\vec{AP}$ and $\vec{AB}$. Then, from the definition of cross product, we have:$$\vec{AP}\times\vec{AB}=|AP|.|AB|.\sin(\theta)\vec{n}$$where $\vec{n}$ is the unit vector at right angles to both $\vec{AP}$ and $\vec{AB}$.

We therefore get:$$|\vec{AP}\times\vec{AB}|=||AP|.|AB|.\sin(\theta)\vec{n}|=|AP|.|AB|.\sin(\theta)$$$$\therefore\frac{|\vec{AP}\times\vec{AB}|}{|AB|}=|AP|.\sin(\theta)$$

Hopefully you can see that this equals $d$

Comment: So that tells me the distance from A to P? I thought I should be finding the perpendicular distance between AB and P?

Comment: No, this gives you the perpendicular distance from AB to P. Note:$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{d}{|AP|}\implies d=|AP|.\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: So essentially taking AP x AB I find the unit vector in the direction of d? I'm just a little confused with the orientation as I thought the cross product would give a vector pointing into the diagram

Comment: Your edited comment just cleared things up

Comment: Cross product will indeed give you a unit vector pointing into the diagram. However, that does not matter as we then take the magnitude of that cross product which effectively removes that unit vector.